# How to express self-referential types using type definitions for existential (forSome) use case correctly in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, existential-type

I'm facing issues due to two scala compiler limitations

1. It's not possible to refer to the type of this (this.type is not it for obv reasons) for cases where you want to write traits which implement common behavior which requires construction of a concrete type. The recommended pattern to work around this is

   ```
   trait Foo[SelfType <: Foo[SelfType]] {      
      this: SelfType =>   
       final def foo: SelfType = newInstance(??? /*do some work*/)
       protected def newInstance(i: Int): SelfType
   }
   ```
2. Scala compiler (fixed in Dotty AFAIK) does not keep track of bounds in existential types (I've found at least 3 bugs filed with the scala github project going back from 2009 and on). This means, given the above type if I were to write a method that take some unknown Foo as such

   ```
   def process(f: Foo[_])
   ```

I may get some weird buggy compiler behavior in certain cases. Instead, I need to manually express to the compiler that the _ here obeys the type bounds to work around its limitations. For that, I'd need to do something like

```
   def process[F <: Foo[F]](f: Foo[F])
```

and invoke the method without passing any type params which hopefully captures this correctly. However, this can make def signatures quite cumbersome if Foo takes other type params leading to a lot of burden for clients. So my question is, is it possible to use type definitions as a shorthand to express such self-referential types correctly. E.g. I've tried all sorts of things.

```
   type SomeFoo = Foo[SelfType] with SelfType forSome { type SelfType <: Foo[SelfType] }
```

but that doesn't seem to quite do it. Somehow the compiler doesn't realize that SelfType is the same unknown type SomeFoo.

I hope this made sense. Thanks for your help. P.S. feel free to suggest renaming the question as it's not super clear right now.

Comment: What is the meta-problem you want to fix here? [How to return the _"current"_ type](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/index.html#how-can-a-method-in-a-superclass-return-a-value-of-the-current-type)?

Comment: Just for personal curiosity: What problem you want to solve with this non-trivial approach?

Comment: thank you both for the quick replies -- if you mean why I need a self-typed Foo, for the reason I explain the post. My super Foo trait can write all the common code for subtypes. The only thing I need to be able is to instantiate the concrete type of Foo. I think that's quite a common requirement. Or do you mean the type definition?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks for the link, I hadn't explored the typeclass way of doing it. This is kind of more the "composition" style rather than the "inheritence" style of solving the issue so might be more robust. It's a very interesting pattern. These self-referential types really suck so I might explore refactoring all my code to use type classes and get rid of SelfType altogether. It does create a bit more boilerplate though. I cannot believe scala doesn't have a good solution for SelfTypes :/

Comment: @Creos Yeah, there are many things in play here. Constructors are weird, you can not abstract them, you can ask for them, you can not think of them as normal methods / functions. Second, in general, having to know which subtype you are means you are violating the parametricity principle, usually is because we approached the problem in a _"wrong"_ way, most of the time we need to know that we actually shouldn't be using inheritance but rather a **typeclass**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez well technically I don't need to know it. The super Foo trait doesn't care what the final type will be. It just needs to be able to express it as a public API (e.g. imagine a "merge" method that is 100% implementable with info only known at the Foo level but the final construction needs to happen in a specific type. So you need to know the correct specific type.) But I hear ya, it's a nuanced thing. I will explore the typeclass solution.